# Laravel - additional condition in a join using DB::raw() query

Tags: laravel

I want to add an "OR" conditional to the `DB::raw` query `join`

I have this query:

```php
$billings = DB::table("billings")
    ->select("billings.plan", "billings.email",DB::raw("COUNT(billings.plan) as total_plans") ,DB::raw("SUM(billings.amount) as total_amount"))
    ->join("users","users.email","=","billings.email")
    ->groupBy("billings.plan")
    ->orderByRaw('billings.plan ASC');
```

In it I have:

```php
->join("users","users.email","=","billings.email")
```

I want to use an "OR" condition:

```php
->join("users","users.email","=","billings.email")
```

or

```php
->join("users","users.phone","=","billings.phone")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$billings = DB::table("billings")
           ->select("billings.plan", "billings.email",DB::raw("COUNT(billings.plan) as total_plans") ,DB::raw("SUM(billings.amount) as total_amount"))
            ->join("users",function($join){
                  $join->on("users.email","=","billings.email");
                  $join->orOn("users.phone","=","billings.phone");
             })
            ->groupBy("billings.plan")
            ->orderByRaw('billings.plan ASC');
```

Answer (score 0):

try below:

```php
$billings = DB::table("billings")
    ->select("billings.plan", "billings.email", DB::raw("COUNT(billings.plan) as total_plans"), DB::raw("SUM(billings.amount) as total_amount"))
    ->join("users", function ($join) {
        $join->on("users.email", "=", "billings.email")
            ->orOn("users.phone", "=", "billings.phone")
    })
    ->groupBy("billings.plan")
    ->orderByRaw('billings.plan ASC');
```

Answer (score 0):

I think for this u need to use advanced join clause.
Something like this:-

```
DB::table('users')
    ->join('contacts', function ($join) {
        $join->on('users.id', '=', 'contacts.user_id')->orOn(...);
    })
    ->get();
```